# How to populate a look up field value from parent to child record

Tags: trigger

I am new to Triggers, I have 2 custom objects Property and Spaces where Property is the parent and spaces are the child records, I want that when a new space is created and does not have a property linked to it, it should auto create the property and also link it to the space, currently my trigger is creating the property but not linking it to the space.

```
trigger createpropertyonspace on Space_Options__c (after insert) {

    List <Property__c> propertyToInsert = new List <Property__c>(); 

    for (Space_Options__c Space: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if (space.Property__c == NULL)
        { 
            Property__c v = new Property__c (); 

            v.Name = space.Old_Signage__c; 

            propertyToInsert.add(v);

        }

    }
    try
    {

        insert propertyToInsert;
    }


    catch(Exception e)
    {
        system.debug('Error: '+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! As is, your question isn't very clear. Based on your current wording, I can't tell which SObject you want to be the 'Parent', and which one you want to be the 'Child'. If you aren't familiar with that terminology, the 'Child' record is the one that has the actual lookup field. For example, `Case` is a child of `Account`. The `Case` SObject has a lookup field called `AccountId` that points to a specific `Account`. A 'Parent' can have many 'Child' records, but a 'Child' record can only have one 'Parent'.

Comment: @Derek F Ok So I have 2 custom objects Property & Spaces where property is the parent and spaces are the child records, I want that when a space is created and has no property linked to it then it should auto create the property and also link it to the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create the records, then populate the lookup field. This is best done in a "before insert" trigger.

```
trigger createpropertyonspace on Space_Options__c (before insert) {
    List <Property__c> propertyToInsert = new List <Property__c>(); 
    List <Space_Options__c> spaceToUpdate = new List <Space_Options__c>();

    for (Space_Options__c Space: Trigger.new) {
        if (space.Property__c == NULL) { 
            propertyToInsert.add(new Property__c (space.Old_Signage__c));
            spaceToUpdate.add(space);
        }

    }
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(propertyToInsert, false);
    for(Integer i = 0, s = propertyToInsert.size(); i < s; i++) {
        if(results[i].isSuccess()) {
            spaceToUpdate[i].Property__c = propertyToInsert[i].Id;
        } else {
            spaceToUpdate[i].Property__c.addError(
                'Failed to create property for this space option. '+
                'The first error was: '+
                results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
        }
    }
    // before trigger automatically updates Trigger.new values; no need to DML here
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Invalid type: Intger at line 13 column 9

Comment: @Shalini Yeah, that was a typo.

Comment: It still gave an error so I just corrected a bit  "Property__c v = new Property__c ();
             v.Name = space.Old_Signage__c;
            propertyToInsert.add(v);:  and now it is working fine. Thank You !!